# OpenCV - findContours hierarchy roots

Tags: opencv

When calling findContours with either RETR_CCOMP or RETR_TREE, is the first item of the hierarchy guaranteed to be the first contour at the top level (ie, previous and parent are both -1)?

I've been searching the documentation and the internet, and it seems to be true, but I can't find it explicitly stated.

Comment: did you see [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71) and [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: I wondered the same thing; the documentation seems to be missing this important guarantee. To be sure, I do a linear scan to find the parentless contours.

Comment: Reported an [issue](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6635).